# how to make Django manage.py runserver exit on DB error?

Tags: django

I have a django webapp running in a docker container with the following command:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]
CMD ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

However, sometimes the django "boot" fails because of temporary database errors:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection self.connect() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection connection = Database.connect(**conn_params) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

The problem is, the process doesn't exit and is still running, Plus, it doesn't retry connecting afterwards.
So it appears healthy from the orchestrator and isn't restarted automatically.

How can I make the command exit when such errors are encountered ?

Comment: does a restart fix the problem? You could try using a docker health check. e.g.: https://howchoo.com/devops/how-to-add-a-health-check-to-your-docker-container

Comment: yes, a manual restart of the container solves it since the error is temporary. I'll try defining the healthcheck properly